# Check if array element already partially exists inside of the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[Amsterdam, Elderly people, Thousand students, Sixteen thousand students, Clean houses]
```

As you can see, there's an entry "`thousand students`" and an entry "`sixteen thousand students`". Is there a way that would let me filter out `thousand students` (and delete this entry), since it already partially exists?

However, just unsetting the element by hand won't work. The array is the result of an API, which means I won't know if there are partial duplicates or not.

thanks.

Edit: Expected result:

```
[Amsterdam, Elderly people, Sixteen thousand students, Clean houses]
```

Comment: you means you want both values right ? can you post expected o/p ?

Comment: @rahul_m No I'd like to delete one. Edited the post too :-)

Comment: means Thousand students will be removed, Sixteen thousand students will stay right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm trying to work out a slicker way without two loops, but this will do it:

```
foreach($array as $k => $a) {
    foreach($array as $b) {
        if(strtolower($a) !== strtolower($b) &&
          (strpos(strtolower($b), strtolower($a)) !== false)) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

- Loop the array and compare each value in lower case to each other value in lower case
- If they are not equal and one is found within the other, use the key to remove the one found in the other

Maybe a little shorter:

```
foreach(array_map('strtolower', $array) as $k => $a) {
    foreach(array_map('strtolower', $array) as $b) {
        if($a !== $b && (strpos($b, $a) !== false)) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function custom_filter( $data ) {
    $data_lc = array_map(function($value){
        return strtolower($value);
    }, $data);

    foreach ($data_lc as $keyA => $valueA) {
        foreach ($data_lc as $keyB => $valueB) {
            if ( $keyA === $keyB ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( false !== strpos($valueA, $valueB) ) {
                if ( strlen($valueA) <= strlen($valueB) ) {
                    unset($data[$keyA]);
                } else {
                    unset($data[$keyB]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

$array = ['Amsterdam', 'Elderly people', 'Thousand students', 'Sixteen thousand students', 'Clean houses'];
print_r( custom_filter( $array ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, however it'll only look for matches at the word level, and it's case sensitive.

```
<?php
$wordsList = [
    'Amsterdam', 'Elderly people', 'Thousand students', 
    'Sixteen thousand students', 'Clean houses',
];

$lookup = array();
foreach ($wordsList as $k => $words) {
    $phrase = '';
    foreach (preg_split('`\s+`', $words, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $word) {
        $phrase .= $word;

        if (in_array($phrase, $words)) {
            unset($wordsList[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```